# MSSQL DB schema and data with all (relation, seq,fk,pk...etc) cli backup tools

Tags: sql-server, linux

Currently I'm trying to get a backup from db with schema level, using mssql-scripter tool, but it seems that does not cover the sequences. Is there any cli tool to do that?

Comment: You are asking about dumping, not backups. Why do you want to do that instead of using a *real* backup? The size will be orders of magnitude smaller and *faster*, the operation can be carried out online (even restores can be online in the Enterprise edition). You can use compressed backups too, saving both space *and* IOPS

Comment: [Backup and restore SQL Server databases on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-backup-and-restore-database?view=sql-server-2017). It's as simple as running `BACKUP DATABASE [demodb] TO DISK = ...` with the appropriate options

Comment: I need a backup on a schema level not whole DB

Comment: **Why**? What are you trying to do and *why*? That's not a backup. That's a script. Other databases may call scripts "logical backups" because they want to charge money for real backups and "Enterprise" editions. SQL Server doesn't have that limitation

Comment: Why do you want to backup only a single schema? How big is the database? Schemas aren't data organization concepts in the first place. They are primarily a security and schema organization tool. They aren't *databases* if that's what you thought. They don't contain accounts, which means backing up only the objects in a schema won't be enough. OTOH you can back up individual filegroups and files if needed.

Comment: I have a big DB separated on multiple schema , so when I need to take a backup, I do not need for whole db, I need it on a partition of it, I mean a schema itself, to save time and size, is there any tool for that ?

Answer (score 0):

On SSMS management studio, Right click on the database --\ generate script.

If you want to cover the dependencies you will find lot of powershell scripts that do this on the web, or use third part tools like redgate

Comment: That's a dump, not a backup